# Scrapy keeps getting blocked

Tags: python, scrapy

I am trying to get a list of movie theaters in the US from http://cinematreasures.org/ as part of my process learning python and scrapy.

I have written a spider to crawl the site but I don't get any response when I run it.
Please find attached pictures of the html tree, my spider, the response when I run the spider and the changes I made to seetings.py.

I was thinking of trying proxy IP's but I don't know how to use them with scrapy. Please help

[image: DOM Tree]

[image: My Default Headers]

[image: Terminal Output]

I have tried the code in scrapy shell and it works fine.

When I try to run it via scrapy crawl listall I get nothing!

I just want to be able to export to csv via pandas if possible.

This is my code:

```
    name = 'listall'
allowed_domains = ['cinematreasures.org']
start_urls = ['http://cinematreasures.org/theaters/united-states?page=1&status=all']
#url = 'http://cinematreasures.org/theaters/united-states?page={}&status=all'
    
def parse(self, response):

    for row in response.xpath('//table//tr')[1:]:
        name =  row.xpath('td//text()')[2].get()
        address = row.xpath('td//text()')[4].get()   
        yield {
            'Name':name,
            'Address':address,
        }
    next_page = response.xpath("//a[@class='next_page']").get()
    if next_page:
        yield scrapy.Request(response.urljoin(next_page))
```

Comment: could you add your code as a code block instead of a screenshot of your code please?

Comment: @RikMulder,  I have added my code as a block

Comment: @TittoCharles add [DOWNLOAD_DELAY](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html?highlight=DOWNLOAD_DELAY#download-delay), see if it helps.

Comment: I have already added DOWNLOAD_DELAY of 14s and changed CONCURRENT_REQUESTS to 1 and it still gives me this response:

[scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `xpath` expressions aren't correct. When you are using relative `xpath` expressions they need to start with a `"./"`  and using class specifiers is much easier than indexing in my opinion.

```
    def parse(self, response):
        for row in response.xpath('//table[@class="list"]//tr'):
            name =  row.xpath('./td[@class="name"]/a/text()').get()
            address = row.xpath('./td[@class="location"]/text()').get()
            yield {
                'Name':name,
                'Address':address,
            }
        next_page = response.xpath("//a[@class='next-page']/@href").get()
        if next_page:
            yield scrapy.Request(response.urljoin(next_page))
```

##### **OUTPUT**

```
...
...
2022-09-09 08:22:07 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://cinematreasures.org/theaters/united-states?page=1&status=all>
{'Name': None, 'Address': None}
2022-09-09 08:22:07 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://cinematreasures.org/theaters/united-states?page=1&status=all>
{'Name': ' Airdome', 'Address': '\n                Ardmore, OK, United States\n              '}
2022-09-09 08:22:07 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://cinematreasures.org/theaters/united-states?page=1&status=all>
{'Name': ' Liberty Theatre', 'Address': '\n                Chickamauga, GA, United States\n              '}
2022-09-09 08:22:07 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://cinematreasures.org/theaters/united-states?page=1&status=all>
{'Name': ' Route 54 Drive-In', 'Address': '\n                Tularosa, NM, United States\n              '}
2022-09-09 08:22:07 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://cinematreasures.org/theaters/united-states?page=1&status=all>
{'Name': '#1 Auto Theatre', 'Address': '\n                Daytona Beach, FL, United States\n              '}
2022-09-09 08:22:07 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://cinematreasures.org/theaters/united-states?page=1&status=all>
{'Name': '#1 Drive-In', 'Address': '\n                Apalachicola, FL, United States\n              '}
2022-09-09 08:22:07 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://cinematreasures.org/theaters/united-states?page=1&status=all>
{'Name': '$1.00 Cinema', 'Address': '\n                Sherman, TX, United States\n              '}
2022-09-09 08:22:07 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://cinematreasures.org/theaters/united-states?page=1&status=all>
{'Name': '$uper Cinemas', 'Address': '\n                East Lansing, MI, United States\n              '}
2022-09-09 08:22:07 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://cinematreasures.org/theaters/united-states?page=1&status=all>
{'Name': '0only Outdoor Theatre', 'Address': '\n                Little Chute, WI, United States\n              '}
2022-09-09 08:22:07 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://cinematreasures.org/theaters/united-states?page=1&status=all>
{'Name': '10 Hi Drive-In', 'Address': '\n                St. Cloud, MN, United States\n              '}
...
...
```